# Переадресация TomCat 8

Tags: url, tomcat

Установил на хостинг `tomcat 8`. Система `Ubuntu 16.04`. 
Открыл сайт, всё работает. Задеплоил свой проект - открылся. И вот тут возникла проблема. На данный моменты мой проект открывается по ссылке: `localhost:8080/MySite/`. Все ссылки которые я делал в проекте начинаются с `/`, к примеру ссылка на админку `/admin`. И при переходе в админку получаю ошибку `404`, при этом `url` получается такой: `localhost:8080/admin`. Подскажите пожалуйста как это исправить? желательно без жёсткой привязки к коду. Может как-то через `xml` томката.

Спасибо.

Comment: Попробуйте url localhost:8080/MySite/admin Все ссылки приложения по идее идут от корня приложения, которым является ресурс MySite Или я неправильно понял вопрос?

Comment: @lospejos Так то правильно. да. НО это мне нужно прописывать вручную и изменять в коде ссылки - везде приписывать `MySite`. А вот как без этого.

Comment: Придётся найти и переписать ВСЕ ссылки с "/admin" на "admin". Та же проблема и с сылкаим на изображения в CSS. Либо развертывайте приложение по пути /, а не по пути /MySite - для этого надо поместить его в папку /webapps/ROOT

Comment: @bobzer уже так и сделал. развернул в `ROOT`.